# Does angularJS have a directive for inserting a script block into the DOM?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a script tag in my DOM that contains a template like the folllowing:

```
<body>

   <div ng-insert='ui'></div>  <!--inject ui here-->

   <script id='ui' type='text/html'>
      <div ng-model='name'></div>
   </script>
</body>
```

...and I wish to add it into the DOM using a directive like the ng-insert I made up above.

I haven't found a built in one to do this yet. ng-include seems to only load in remote templates. I think this would  be a reasonably simple directive to write, which I may try, but I wanted to make sure I'm not reinventing something that already exists.

Comment: AFAIK: No. But it should be possible to write one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-include` can be used in combination with predefined templates using `type="text/ng-template"` on a `script` tag.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="templateId.html">
  This is the content of the template
</script>
```

Note: the `script` tag containing the template does not need to be included in the head of the document, but it must be below the `ng-app` definition.

later use this to get the template:

```
<div ng-include="'templateId.html'"></div>
```

Note: the template's name is in single quotes, as a string.

You can also get this template via JavaScript:

```
$templateCache.get('templateId.html')
```

Refernces:

- [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:script](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ascript)
- [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$templateCache](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24templateCache)

Comment: Thanks. Only downside I see is that ng-include creates a new scope which I wasn't intending. But maybe that's not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think `ng-include` and `script type="text/ng-template"` is what you're looking for
http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/MfHa6/